# jQuery Validation, custom rule uses required method doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to create a custom validation rule, which uses some different methods to check the input. One of them, is `required` rule.

But the code doesn't work. It ignores empty inputs and says they're valid.

The code:

```
$("#test-form").validate({
    rules: {
        test: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u5now2e5/

What's wrong? Note that, I don't want to use `required` css class. Because it depends on some other fields.

Comment: This wont work because test is a classname, but rules are set/ defined via the name of the field. If you want to add a custom class rule use: addClassRules:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/

Comment: You can use http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/

Comment: Note that `.addClassRules()` is limited to simply creating a "compound" rule composed of standard rules and declaring that "compound" rule to fields using a class name.  If you want to create a whole new rule, or a rule you can declare within `.validate()`, you must use `.addMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a unique `name` attribute on the input; and when you declare rules within `.validate()` it can only be referenced via that `name` attribute.

```
<input type="text" id="input-1" class="test" name="test" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#test-form").validate({
    rules: {
        test: {  // <- NAME of input field
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5now2e5/2/

---

To create a "custom" rule, you would use [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).  But again, every input must still have a unique `name` attribute, and when you declare the rule within `.validate()`, it can only be referenced by `name`.